# How to count rows from multiple tables using one query

Tags: php, mysqli

My DB contains information about specific projects. Each project is made of multiple parts, and each part has one or more photo galleries. I want to know if I can count the number of project parts, galleries and photos associated with any given project using only one query. Currently there is 1 project in the system that has 3 parts, 5 galleries and 302 photos.

This query (with thanks to many here from SO) works fine to count the number of parts per project, which currently is 3:

```
// count number of parts per project
$conn = dbConnect('query');
$galNumb = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pj_parts WHERE pj_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($galNumb);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $project);
$stmt->bind_result($galTotal);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
```

Can this be changed to count not only the number of parts (pj_part) but also count the number of galleries and photos from their respective tables? I'm trying to streamline my queries and learn more about making my code efficient. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

UPDATE:

I'm not certain how to do the table structure formatting here, but here it is in plain text:

```
pj_parts
pj_part_id (primary key)
pj_id (project number)
pj_part (part number within project)

pj_part_galleries
pj_gallery_id (primary key)
pj_id (project number)
pj_part (part number within project)
pj_gallery (gallery number)

pj_photos
pj_photo_id (primary key)
pj_id (project number)
pj_part (part number within project)
pj_gallery_number
```

I hope this helps, if not, please let me know what to do to reformat it.

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: First I need to know what your other tables are and what their foriegn key are in order to help

Answer (score 2):

If you use UNION

```
SELECT 'pj_parts' as tablename, COUNT(*) as c 
    FROM pj_parts WHERE something=something
UNION 
SELECT 'pj_galleries' as tablename, COUNT(*) as c 
    FROM some_other_table WHERE something=something
UNION 
SELECT 'pj_photos' as tablename, COUNT(*) as c 
    FROM some_other_other_table WHERE something=something
```

you'll get this

```
tablename         |   c
------------------+--------
pj_parts          |  3
pj_galleries      |  5
pj_photos         |  302
```

which you can iterate through to perhaps populate an array or whatever (question doesn't specify)

Comment: but are these tabled joined? Because the other answers assume that they are and, if so, those answers use a better method.

Comment: The tables are not joined, I simply want to count the number of items per tabel based on a specific project number.

Comment: but I suspect, as others assumed that pj_galleries has an id which also exists in pj_parts, otherwise how do you know which gallery belongs to which part? It would help if you provided your table structure.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT p.pj_part_id) AS parts,
COUNT(DISTINCT g.pj_gallery_id) AS galleries,
COUNT(DISTINCT ph.pj_photo_id) AS photos,
 FROM 
pj_parts p
LEFT JOIN pj_part_galleries g ON (g.pj_part = p.pj_part_id)
LEFT JOIN pj_part_photos ph ON (ph.pj_part = p.pj_part_id)
WHERE p.pj_id = ?
```

You'll have to add in the correct table/column names.

Edit:
If using mysqli you can do the following to bind:
Replace:

```
$stmt->bind_result($galTotal);
```

With:

```
$stmt->bind_result($partsTotal,$galleriesCount,$photosCount);
```

NB: Here I've changed $galTotal to $partsTotal.

Edit2: Updated to use column/table names.

Comment: @ D Stanley, many thanks! How do I then bind the results in my prepared statement shown above so that I can echo the results?

Comment: the above for you as well...and thank you. I'm going to try these now.

Comment: Updated to use table and column names.

Comment: I'm getting 'Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object' on line 50 which is `$stmt->bind_param('i', $project);` and `$project` is the query string variable carrying the project number to the page (in this case, it's 1).

Comment: This is a better answer now we can see what's joined where, but just one note - you don't need pj_part in the photos table as that table should join with pj_galleries using a pj_gallery_id, - it doesn't need to know what pj_part it's in because it can find that via the pj_galleries table

Comment: @wordman This suggests that `$stmt00` isn't an object. Above you use `$stm`. Could this be a typo?

Comment: @popnoodles let me chew on that. My brain is a bit squished as it is, but interesting food for thought.

Comment: @Jim, yes, typo city. I fixed it. The error is still coming up though.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing on your structure, but something like this?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.part_id) parts ,
    COUNT(DISTINCT g.gal_id) galleries ,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ps.pic_id) photos
FROM pj_parts p
    LEFT JOIN {galleries} g on p.part_id = g.part_id
    LEFT JOIN {photos} ps on g.gal_id = ps.gal_id
WHERE p.pj_id = ?
```